# why the variable was reset after if statements? (C++)

Tags: c++

why the variable was reset after if statements

print the following message:

recv len1: 122

recv len2: 0

```
R *r;

void on_recv(struct bufferevent *bev, void *arg)
{
    struct evbuffer *src;
    size_t len;

    src = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    len = evbuffer_get_length(src);
    ......

    BaseHandler *handler = r->get_handler();
    char data[MAX_BUFSIZE] = { 0 };
    char new_data[MAX_BUFSIZE] = { 0 };
    evbuffer_copyout(src, data, len);
    LOGE("recv len1: %d\n", len);
    if (handler->handle(data, new_data)) {
        LOGE("recv len2: %d\n", len);
    }

    ......

}
```

Comment: _why the variable was reset after if statements_ Which variable? Please, elaborate your question. A [mcve] would be appreciated as well.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, then please leave the C tag out of it. C++ and C are two very different languages.

Comment: *"why the variable was reset"* Without seeing the rest of your program, who knows? Perhaps `handler->handle` invokes some UB that messes with the stack and changes `len` that way. Or maybe `LOGE` is a macro that assigns to `len`. Or it is misleading in other ways, doesn't actually print `len` and maintains some state elsewhere to cause the different results.

Comment: If it's about `len` - this smells like [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). I would carefully watch for out of range accesses.

Comment: You should consider running a debug-build of your program in a memory debugger tool (like e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). That should help you find possible out-of-bounds writes as well as other possible problems.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the `handle` method. You should show us at  least this method. You can [edit]  your question.

Comment: Do not write pseudocode examples, defect is in your actual code, and not where you imagine it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a buffer-overflow: You are writing past the end of either `data` or `new_data` and so you are overwriting `len` with NUL bytes apparently.

**Solution:** Pass the actual buffer sizes to function `handle()` and make sure this does not access (read and write) beyond the end of the passed arrays.

You can also print `handler` before and within the `if()`. This should also get corrupted as it is between `len` and the arrays.